# How to show an image that a user has uploaded

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm trying to show an image that a user has uploaded as part of a recipe but keep getting an error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1
>   table recipes has no column named amount (SQL: insert into "recipes"
>   ("image", "title", "servings", "ingredients", "amount",
>   "instructions", "user_id", "updated_at", "created_at") values
>   (uploads/U7lIutRFmbpyDz6EOUaExPGh5nYHElXZHcJv56CT.jpeg, pasta recipe,
>   4, pasta, 50g, cook it, 9, 2020-03-04 12:23:16, 2020-03-04 12:23:16))

It stores the image ok but nothing else.

[image]

Not sure on how to get the other fields to store either.

Below is the controller for recipes

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZpYC.png)

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: hello, the error says you dont have column amount in your database

Comment: Hi. Please add your controller code to the question.

Comment: Please add your controller and Recipes Model Code

Comment: Looks like the `amount` is missing in your fillable array in the model.

Comment: I guess you added amount after first migration, so you need to run `php artisan migration:fresh`.
Note: make sure you are in development environment before running this command ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it come to migrations, there's a general rule you should follow: **Don't modify migrations after they have been run, unless you have the specific intent of re-running that migration**. Generally, this requires a refresh of your database, and truncation of data.

You should make a new migration, like `add_amount_to_recipies.php`, which has the sole purpose of adding this new column in `public function up()`, and removing it in `public function down()`:

```
public function up(){
  Schema::table('recipies', function($table) {
    $table->string('amount');
  });
}

public function down(){
  Schema::table('recipies', function($table) {
    $table->dropColumn('amount');
  });
}
```

Then, run `php artisan migrate`. This will add the column to the table without modifying the existing data.